# Having trouble using the "addRole" method

Tags: discord.js

I'm having some issues using the `addRole` property.

Here is my code:

```js
let role = client.guilds.get(targetserver).createRole({ name: "OP", permissions: [8] , color: "#ff0000"});
let rolefind = client.guilds.get(targetserver).roles.find("name", "OP")
client.guilds.get(targetserver).members.get(urid).addRole(rolefind)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!  You should [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.  In this case -- what is the error you are getting?  Can you provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
let role = await client.guilds.get(targetserver).createRole({ name: "OP", permissions: [8], color: "#ff0000"});
```

With `await` because guild.createRole is a function that returns a promise.